# How to get all IDs of products fpr current page in magento

Tags: magento

I encounter a huge problem with retrieving Product IDs for current page.

Current page is /catalog/product/list

and all data is taken with class

> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List

There is method

> $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

with the help of it all product items is returned as a collection

Is there any way to get only IDs of Products?

I need in it because I want to make some remote request with IDs array for getting some additional values before retrieving all data by $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
??

Because doing 2 foreach is not a good idea.

> foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {    $arrIds[] =
>   $_product->getId(); }
>
> foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) { show all products here }

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in magento you have the $collection->getAllIds() method